# connecting asp.net website to azure mobile services database

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-mobile-services

I was wondering if it is possible to insert and read from an azure mobile services database through an asp.net mvc application. At the moment both are using separate databases and have data in them but I would like the website to have CRUD functionality with the mobile services tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Mobile Services database - it's just a standard Azure SQL Database which you can open and utilise as any other.

Log into the Azure Management Portal and select your Mobile Service. Click on the 'Configure' tab and you will find the database and server details at the top of the screen.

If you click on the arrow next to the database it will navigate you to the database. Open the Dashboard page and on the right you will see an option that reads 'Show connection strings'. Click that and you'll have what you need for your MVC application.

Comment: You should use the same schema name for your MVC app as your mobile service. The schema name is your mobile service name, with dashes replaced with underscores.